# fetch entry from mongodb by objectid using mongojs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongojs

i created an web application with node.js and mongo.js where i can type in data into an html page and send it so my mongodb databse.
now i want to type in the objectid in my html page and get back my entry.
this is my html code:

```
<div class="fetch" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <center><b>ID:&nbsp;</b><input class="form-fetch" ng-model="patient._id">&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="fetchPatient(patient._id)">Fetch Patient</button></center>
</div>
```

this is my controller.js:

```
    $scope.fetchPatient = function (id) {
    console.log($scope.patient._id);
    $http.get('/patientlist/:id').success(function (response) {
    });
    }
```

and this is my server.js:

```
app.get('/patientlist/:id', function (req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;
console.log(id);
db.patientlist.findOne({ _id: mongojs.ObjectId(id) }, function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the _id is created by you so don't put `ObjectId` around it:

```
db.patientlist.findOne({ _id: id }, function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
});
```

`ObjectId` is for the _id auto-generated by MongoDB.

Comment: i want so type in the autogenerated objectid in order to get the entry displayed on my html page.